# MaskedInput in Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I'm trying to implement MaskedInput TextBox at WP8. The common scenario: empty field, user see mask, e.g. `###-##-##`. Then he starts to input values: `1##-##-##`, `21#-##-##`, `321-##-##`, `432-1#-##` and so on. I thought about using `TextSelection` property and `TextChanged` event to maintain right selection position and on-fly mask replacing with values. The problem is that I can't use different color for mask, as it share the same input with value. Also I can't use another `TextBox` or `TextBlock` behind active, because mask characters will have different width with value (e.g. `###` will not align with `W##`). Is there some way to support multiple foreground at `TextBox` or to adjust characters width to same value?

UPD: Well, I know about monospacing fonts. Guess, it's the only way to get what I need. But is there some way to implement that feature in one TextBox?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You will Use like this.

```
<TextBlock>
   <Run Text="*" Foreground="#FFE10101"/><Run Text="Required Line" />
   <Run Text="Red" Foreground="Red"/>
   <Run Text="Blue" Foreground="Blue"/>
   <Run Text="{Binding yourString, StringFormat='with \{0\} a different color!'}" Foreground="Orange"/>
</TextBlock>
```

For More Reference Refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365567/multiple-colors-in-textblock/11852742#11852742)

Comment: Not `TextBlock` but `TextBox`