# UWP How to bind to two values?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10

I have a `DownloadModel` which contains two properties. I want to show summary of those two properties in a single `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind DownloadModel.Part1.Progress, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Is there any way to pass `Download.Part1.Progress` and `Download.Part2.Progress` together then show summary of both in the `TextBlock`?

*(If it's possible to do so with `Binding` instead of `x:Bind` that will be fine too)*
Thanks.

Comment: Typically this would be solved with MultiBinding but that doesn't seem to exist in UWP

Comment: In MVVM pattern, you would create the ViewModel that translates between the model and the view. Your ViewModel would expose a public property `Progress` that performs the logic operation, and the view binds to it.

Comment: TextBlock Can be split to `Run` inside content. Use two `Run` and Bind Each one's `Text` Property.

Comment: @AVKNaidu has the right idea. If you need an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8365567/multiple-colors-in-textblock/11852742)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can actually use `Run` inside a `TextBlock`. You can use it like this:

For example, I have these two strings:

```
    private string FirstText = "This is the first text.";
    private string SecondText = "This is the second text.";
```

I have this in my XAML:

```
    <TextBlock Foreground="Black">
        <Run Text="{x:Bind FirstText}"/>
        <Run Text="{x:Bind SecondText}"/>
    </TextBlock>
```

And This is how the app looks like:

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: Good point! But I actually think that if you need to display to values and there is no Control to to this, just create UserControl :)